# Satellite Terrain Mapping

Tags: add-on

I use a utlity called TERRALAND in Unity that will pull in a digital elevation map (DEM) of a selected area and overlay it with satellite imagery of that area.  I've used a similar utility in Cinema 4D called DEMearth. I have two questions: (1) Is there a similar addon for Blender 2.8x?  (2) How would I export the TERRALAND terrain object from Unity into Blender.  I've researched but found little information.

Answer (score 2):

blendergis is an excellent free addon for adding terrain and satellite found on github. easy to use a little tricky to install

Comment: Why is it tricky?

Comment: well its not too tricky if i remember i had to add 2 dependencies. https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki

Answer (score 1):

You can discount my perceptions as a novice. I tried multiple times to install BLenderGIS by pointing to the BlenderGISmaster folder that had already been unpacked from the ZIP. Nothing happened and no new entry appeared in the addon listings  (I was trying to load it into the  "community" addons section.
It succeeded only when pointing to the original zip file
  I saw a reference somehwhere that Blender could install from a zip but nowhere have I seen a statement that the addon MUST  be in ZIP form in order for the install script to put it where ever it goes 
I propose that the addon  install interface be labeled as "Install from ZIP only" because this appears to be an undocumented requirement,